# Reproductor Musica con JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Estoy construyendo un pequeño reproductor mp3 con ***javascript*** y me ha surgido un imprevisto. En el botón de siguiente y anterior cuando hago **`click`** y llamo a los eventos, realiza la operación del **`current`** para incrementar o decrementar el índice de la canción, pero luego no ejecuta correctamente la función `myAudio.play();`.

Os dejo el código para que le echéis un vistazo y me ayudáis a encontrar el problema de esto:

Código JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
    //Almaceno las canciones en un array
    var canciones = ["adictiva","desde el corazon","mocca","say my name"];
    //Indice de la cancion por defecto a 0
    var current = 0;
    //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio     
    myAudio = document.querySelector("#myAudio");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton play
    playBtn = document.querySelector("#play");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton pause
    pauseBtn = document.querySelector("#pause");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton stop
    stopBtn = document.querySelector("#stop");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton anterior
    anteriorBtn = document.querySelector("#anterior");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton siguiente
    siguienteBtn = document.querySelector("#siguiente");

    //Funciones del reproductor de musica
    playBtn.addEventListener('click', function play(){
        //Cambia la cancion
        myAudio.innerHTML = "<source src='Canciones/"+canciones[current]+".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>";
        console.log(myAudio);
        //Carga la cancion
        myAudio.load();
        //Reproduce la canción
        myAudio.play();
        document.querySelector("#musicaactual").innerHTML = "Reproduciendo ahora: "+canciones[current];
    });

    pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function pause(){
        //Pausar canción
        myAudio.pause();
    });

    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function stop(){
        //Pausar canción
        myAudio.pause();
        //El contador lo dejo a 0 para que empieze desde nuevo
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
    });

    anteriorBtn.addEventListener('click', function anterior(){
        if(current > 0){
            current--;

        }
        myAudio.play();

    });

    siguienteBtn.addEventListener('click', function siguiente(){
        if(current < canciones.length-1){
            current++;
        }

        myAudio.play();

    });
});
```

Código HTML:

```
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="Canciones/adictiva.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div id="musicaactual"></div>
<!-- Reproductor MP3 -->
<div class="mp3">
    <div class="screen">
        <p id="info-track"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="controles">
        <button id="play">Play</button>
        <button id="pause">Pause</button>
        <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="primera">Primera</button>
        <button id="anterior">Anterior</button>
        <button id="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
        <button id="ultima">Ultima</button>
        <!-- Control para deslizar la barra de volumen y baja o subir volumen -->
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.1"  id="volumen">
        <!-- Control para deslizar la barra para avanzar o retroceder la canción -->
        <button>Control deslizar</button>
        <button>Aleatorio</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Porqué no le pasas `current` y `myAudio` a tu función callback?

Comment: Porque lo tengo declarado arriba y es global para todas las funciones callback que hago

Comment: Creo que el problema está que no estás actualizando el objeto `myAudio` con el valor correcto de la canción. Si bien, actualizas `current`, no actualizas luego `source`. Te recomiendo que la función `play` la declares fuera del evento `click` del botón `playBtn`. Así podrás llamarla tanto en el evento `click` de `playBtn` como en el evento `click` de `anteriorBtn` y `siguienteBtn`. Prueba eso y me comentas.